# A million dollars "is" still needed, or "are" still needed?

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-vs-plural

Suppose that I'm trying to raise money for a fancy black tie gala, and I want to let the guests know how far we still are from the goal.

Should I say

> One million dollars **is** still needed to reach our goal.

or

> One million dollars **are** still needed to reach our goal.

I've heard people say it both ways and neither of them sound outright wrong.

Comment: Money is uncountable, isn't it? So, we should use **is**, not *are* in this case.

Comment: @XPMai I usually try to count my money.

Comment: @DCShannon, money could be collective, not fixed. So, it's uncountable. Notes/coins are countable.

Comment: @XPMai Sorry, that was a little joke.

Comment: @XPMai The word *money* is an uncountable noun. But a sum of *dollars* can be considered as either singular or plural, and thus take either a singular or plural verb.

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question.

Perhaps someone else can give a more grammatically based answer, but let me respond from the position of how those *sound* to a native speaker.

Those both sound fine to my ear. For comparison, let's remove a few words from the sentence in two different ways:

> 1. One is still needed to reach our goal.
> 2. Dollars are still needed to reach our goal.

In both those examples it's clear which verb to use, but talking about "**one** million dollar**s**" is sort of both singular and plural, so you'll hear both. "A million dollars" can be viewed as a unit, but each dollar is also a thing, and there are many of them.

Even though those both sound fine, I too am not entirely sure which is correct, and I might doubt myself if I used either one in a formal setting. To sidestep this issue, I would phrase the statement like so:

> We still need a million dollars to reach our goal.

If I *had* to choose one of the two phrasings, I would pick the singular, with 'is'. This is because I view "a million dollars" more as a unit or quantity than as a collection of individual dollars.

> The quantity of a million dollars *is* still needed to reach our goal.

'Is' matches quantity.

Answer (score -1):

One million dollars is a single quantity, so the correct verb would be *is*. The only situation I can think of in which you'd say *are* would be if each individual donation was one dollar, not likely for a fancy black tie gala.