# Money - Countable or Uncountable noun

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

[This](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/countable-nouns) page suggests that we use `much` with only uncountable nouns whereas the use of `many/several` is limited to countable nouns only. So I conclude that `money` is uncountable noun as I've heard people saying phrases like

> So much money!

But, We do count the money in our daily life then why is it that `money` is considered an uncountable noun instead of countable? What if I say

> I have $500 to spend

Wouldn't the money be considered countable in this case?

**Edit**
The question may be considered duplicate of the suggested question but, in my opinion, the question on that link itself is not answered properly.

Comment: You might want to check this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6296/is-money-a-countable-noun

Comment: @shin : That didn't answer my question.In fact it confused me. Every answer to that question has a different opinion and none of which explains why (or why not) money is uncountable. They simply state it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sugar is uncountable: grains of sugar are countable.

Air is uncountable: oxygen molecules are countable.

Money is uncountable: dollars are countable.

Sometimes we want to use a collective term for stuff that you use to buy things with- that's money. When you want to start quantifying (counting) it, you have to use a currency- dollars, dinars, yen, euros.

Comment: I figured that much out myself as I've mentioned in the question but how would I explain it to someone upon being asked? There's got to be some logic or explanation behind it.

Comment: The edited version explains it all. Just one last thing to ask - Is every currency considered as countable including Indian Rupee? I'm asking this because the answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/75877/29795) says otherwise. It says `few Rupees` doesn't make sense which inclines me to conclude that `Rupees` is not considered countable? @JavaLatte

Comment: If you read the whole sentence, he goes on to say is that "a few Rupees" would be a better way of expressing it. "few" and "a few" are both used for countable things, but have slightly different meanings.

Comment: I think the best way to explain it is that "money" the *word* is uncountable: you can't have "a money".  Money the *concept* is countable.  "Rupees" are money, but they're not the *word* "money". So you can have "five rupees" but not "five moneys".

Answer (score 5):

This is a very common problem for learners of all languages (and I've even seen some native-speaker English teachers make big mistakes with this in English lessons!).

We like to talk about *things* being countable, but really it is nouns that are countable (even when the noun may be both countable and uncountable).

The word *money* gives us the idea of *general* money. When we think about this idea, we don't think about numbers. This is the same way that we don't think about numbers when we think about water.

When we think about water, we can think about the amount of water we have. We think about litres (or pints or gallons). Now, we don't usually have a million waters, but we can very easily have a million *litres* of water. The same thing happens with money. We don't usually have *a million moneys*. But we can have *a million pounds*, or *a million yen* or *a million dollars*.

This may seem strange when you think about it. An easy way to understand it though is to think about your own language. What is the word for *money* in your language? Can you say: *5 money* in your language? You can't!

What is the currency in your country in your language (dollars, yen, roubles, lira etc)? Can you say "*5 (X)*" —5 dollars, 5 yen, 5 roubles, 5 lira, 5 (currency)s— in your language?

Yes you can!

It works the same way in English too!

Answer (score 4):

I see how difficult it can be to convey simple ideas such as countable or uncountable to speakers of non-European languages.

You are right, you can count your money, but when counting you don't say I have one money or two or three moneys, you say I have one Euro/dollar/Rupie or two Euros/dollars/Rupees.

"money" is a collective noun as furniture and you can't say one/two/three moneys. If this idea is difficult for you to understand - which may absolutely understandable - you have to learn it mechanically.